# TFS- Revision graph like Subversion

Tags: svn, tfs, revision-graph

Is there a way to see revisions/changeset to a repository in TFS just like how we can see revisions/branches in SVN using revision graph?

Edit: I am using TortoiseSVN for SVN client

Comment: Where do you see the 'revision graph' in Subversion? In TortoiseSVN or in Subclipse? Or Somewhere else? The Subversion project doesn't deliver this feature.

Comment: With TortoiseSVN, open Repo-Browser, select a folder ("trunk" for example) and right-clik on it and select Revision Graph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TFS 2010 has such feature, with 2008 you may take a look at [TFS Follow Branch History](http://tfsbranchhistory.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Please explain how to get to this feature in TFS 2010+. Simply stating it exists is not a helpful answer (downvoted accordingly).

Comment: I think this might be the feature you are referring to, but it doesn't show revisions (checkins), just branches: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged