# Is there a way to see revisions/changeset to a repository in TFS just like how we can see revisions/branches in SVN using revision graph?

Tags: svn, tfs

Is there a way to see revisions/changeset to a repository in TFS just like how we can see revisions/branches in SVN using revision graph?

i m currently using TFS

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915986/tfs-revision-graph-like-subversion

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, TFS 2008 does not provide a revision graph feature.  SVN does not provide this directly either though.  TortoiseSVN, Eclipse, and others do it on SVN's behalf.  TFS 2010 launching in a few months and available in Beta 2 now does provide branching and changeset graphs to follow the path of a changeset or branch hierarchy.